# Extract log Messages between 2 time stamp patterns in RegEX

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, pattern-matching

i have the below log file, am writing a log monitoring using NodeJS. my parser is based on Regex, so if i recieved in the log file new lines that can be translated into multiple log messages i should be able to extract them. for that i need a rtegex to extract the variouys log messages

```
Fri Jan 24 05:28:57 2014
MEMORY_TARGET defaulting to 1128267776.
* instance_number obtained from CSS = 1, checking for the existence of node 0... 
* node 0 does not exist. instance_number = 1 
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Initial number of CPU is 48
Number of processor cores in the system is 24
Number of processor sockets in the system is 12
Private Interface 'nxge20:1' configured from GPnP for use as a private interconnect.
abc
  [name='nxge20:1', type=1, ip=169.254.121.29, mac=00-21-28-0e-8c-ae-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-2f-ff-ff, net=169.254.0.0/16, mask=255.255.0.0, use=haip:cluster_interconnect/62]
Public Interface 'nxge0' configured from GPnP for use as a public interface.
  [name='nxge0', type=1, ip=172.20.70.18, mac=00-21-28-0e-94-ce-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-2f-ff-ff, net=172.20.70.0/24, mask=255.255.255.0, use=public/1]
Public Interface 'nxge21' configured from GPnP for use as a public interface.
  [name='nxge21', type=1, ip=100.100.100.1, mac=00-21-28-0e-8c-af-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-2f-ff-ff, net=100.100.100.0/23, mask=255.255.254.0, use=public/1]
Shared memory segment for instance monitoring created
CELL communication is configured to use 0 interface(s):
CELL IP affinity details:
    NUMA status: NUMA system w/ 3 process groups
    cellaffinity.ora status: cannot find affinity map at '/etc/oracle/cell/network-config/cellaffinity.ora' (see trace file for details)
CELL communication will use 1 IP group(s):
    Grp 0: 
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 3
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as /dbtop/grid/dbs/arch
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
NOTE: Volume support  enabled
NUMA system with 3 nodes detected
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Real Application Clusters and Automatic Storage Management options.
ORACLE_HOME = /dbtop/grid
System name:    SunOS
Node name:  sec33-e
Release:    5.10
Version:    Generic_142909-17
Machine:    sun4u
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile /dbtop/asm/dbs/spfile+ASM.ora
System parameters with non-default values:
  large_pool_size          = 12M
  instance_type            = "asm"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  asm_diskstring           = "/dev/rdsk/*"
  asm_diskgroups           = "WFREC"
  asm_diskgroups           = "WFDATA"
  asm_power_limit          = 7
  diagnostic_dest          = "/dbtop/app/oracle"
Cluster communication is configured to use the following interface(s) for this instance
  169.254.121.29
cluster interconnect IPC version:Oracle UDP/IP (generic)
IPC Vendor 1 proto 2
Fri Jan 24 05:29:03 2014
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=17520 
Fri Jan 24 05:29:04 2014
PSP0 started with pid=3, OS id=17521 
Fri Jan 24 05:29:05 2014
VKTM started with pid=4, OS id=17522 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
```

i have tried to match the datatime and place in a group using the below regex:

```
(\w{1,3} \w{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4})
```

which is matching the timestamp, how can i grap the rest of the log message in a the second group

Comment: See [`/^([a-z]{1,3} [a-z]{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4})\r?\n(.*(?:\r?\n(?![a-z]{1,3} [a-z]{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4}).*)*)/gmi`](https://regex101.com/r/1hRWqW/1).

Comment: thanks a lot its working :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
/^([a-z]{1,3} [a-z]{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4})\r?\n(.*(?:\r?\n(?![a-z]{1,3} [a-z]{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4}).*)*)/igm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1hRWqW/1).

The pattern includes your pattern and a an additional part that matches up to that pattern or end of text.

- `^` - start of a line
- `([a-z]{1,3} [a-z]{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4})`  - Group 1 matching the time stamp
- `\r?\n` - a line break
- `(.*(?:\r?\n(?![a-z]{1,3} [a-z]{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4}).*)*)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ sequences of:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the line break char
  - `(?:\r?\n(?![a-z]{1,3} [a-z]{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4}).*)*` - zero or more occurrences of:

    - `\r?\n(?![a-z]{1,3} [a-z]{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4})` - a line break that is not followed with the timestamp pattern
    - `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the line break char.

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /^([a-z]{1,3} [a-z]{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4})\r?\n(.*(?:\r?\n(?![a-z]{1,3} [a-z]{1,3} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{4}).*)*)/gmi;
var str = "Fri Jan 24 05:28:57 2014\r\nMEMORY_TARGET defaulting to 1128267776.\r\n* instance_number obtained from CSS = 1, checking for the existence of node 0... \r\n* node 0 does not exist. instance_number = 1 \r\nStarting ORACLE instance (normal)\r\nLICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0\r\nLICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0\r\nInitial number of CPU is 48\r\nNumber of processor cores in the system is 24\r\nNumber of processor sockets in the system is 12\r\nPrivate Interface 'nxge20:1' configured from GPnP for use as a private interconnect.\r\nabc\r\n  [name='nxge20:1', type=1, ip=169.254.121.29, mac=00-21-28-0e-8c-ae-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-2f-ff-ff, net=169.254.0.0/16, mask=255.255.0.0, use=haip:cluster_interconnect/62]\r\nPublic Interface 'nxge0' configured from GPnP for use as a public interface.\r\n  [name='nxge0', type=1, ip=172.20.70.18, mac=00-21-28-0e-94-ce-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-2f-ff-ff, net=172.20.70.0/24, mask=255.255.255.0, use=public/1]\r\nPublic Interface 'nxge21' configured from GPnP for use as a public interface.\r\n  [name='nxge21', type=1, ip=100.100.100.1, mac=00-21-28-0e-8c-af-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-2f-ff-ff, net=100.100.100.0/23, mask=255.255.254.0, use=public/1]\r\nShared memory segment for instance monitoring created\r\nCELL communication is configured to use 0 interface(s):\r\nCELL IP affinity details:\r\n    NUMA status: NUMA system w/ 3 process groups\r\n    cellaffinity.ora status: cannot find affinity map at '/etc/oracle/cell/network-config/cellaffinity.ora' (see trace file for details)\r\nCELL communication will use 1 IP group(s):\r\n    Grp 0: \r\nPicked latch-free SCN scheme 3\r\nUsing LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as /dbtop/grid/dbs/arch\r\nAutotune of undo retention is turned on. \r\nLICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0\r\nSYS auditing is disabled\r\nNOTE: Volume support  enabled\r\nNUMA system with 3 nodes detected\r\nStarting up:\r\nOracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production\r\nWith the Real Application Clusters and Automatic Storage Management options.\r\nORACLE_HOME = /dbtop/grid\r\nSystem name:    SunOS\r\nNode name:  sec33-e\r\nRelease:    5.10\r\nVersion:    Generic_142909-17\r\nMachine:    sun4u\r\nUsing parameter settings in server-side spfile /dbtop/asm/dbs/spfile+ASM.ora\r\nSystem parameters with non-default values:\r\n  large_pool_size          = 12M\r\n  instance_type            = \"asm\"\r\n  remote_login_passwordfile= \"EXCLUSIVE\"\r\n  asm_diskstring           = \"/dev/rdsk/*\"\r\n  asm_diskgroups           = \"WFREC\"\r\n  asm_diskgroups           = \"WFDATA\"\r\n  asm_power_limit          = 7\r\n  diagnostic_dest          = \"/dbtop/app/oracle\"\r\nCluster communication is configured to use the following interface(s) for this instance\r\n  169.254.121.29\r\ncluster interconnect IPC version:Oracle UDP/IP (generic)\r\nIPC Vendor 1 proto 2\r\nFri Jan 24 05:29:03 2014\r\nPMON started with pid=2, OS id=17520 \r\nFri Jan 24 05:29:04 2014\r\nPSP0 started with pid=3, OS id=17521 \r\nFri Jan 24 05:29:05 2014\r\nVKTM started with pid=4, OS id=17522 at elevated priority\r\nVKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms";
var m, res = [];

while ((m = rx.exec(str)) !== null) {
     res.push([m[1], m[2]]);
}
console.log(res);
```